# When I activate the data layer using a GTM server-side plugin, the "Add-to-Cart" remove button stops working

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side, google-datalayer

I created a unique theme for my WooCommerce business and chose to add a GTM server-side plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtm-server-side/ to improve my analytics, however, something went wrong. It wasn't working properly when customers wanted to remove items from their shopping carts.
[This item removal icon is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUEob.png)
This is a serious problem since it may irritate clients to the point that they walk away empty-handed. When shoppers attempted to remove products from their shopping carts—a fundamental and necessary function for a seamless shopping experience—the issue surfaced. When the data layer was activated, this feature stopped working properly. It's a serious problem because it interferes with customers' ability to remove things from their carts, which could lead to cart abandonment and lost income.

I went through the plugin's code to find the woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link function and verified the names of all the other staff members. When the data layer is deactivated, everything functions as intended, but to track events, the data layer must be activated.
[Data Layer activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MiSD.png)
[Woocommerce cart item remove link hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov9jA.png)